# Integrating Python package/project into apache KARAF

Tags: python, apache-karaf, karaf, karaf-maven-plugin

I am new to Apache Karaf. after spending 2 days on internet got some idea about what the KARAF is for. My requirement is to integrating some of the Python projects into the Apache Karaf container.

> Q1.) is it possible to integrate Python project/application/package in
>   Karaf?
>
> Q2.) Any dependencies on versions? which version of Karaf should be
>   used with which version of Python? OS dependencies ?
>
> Q3.) Any link to tutorials or examples or video tutorial that can explain in detail

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you got what Karaf is about, it's an OSGi Container for OSGi Java application. Dunno how Python a completely different language comes into play here.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck: yes.. I want to create OSGI container with mypython project register my service into karaf and access it

Comment: so you're trying to use jython then? 
I still don't see the point, Python is a completely different language. OSGi is a framework running on top of the JVM (Java). While Python is a script language. If you want to execute Python code in Java you'll need something else first, like Jython. But Jython hasn't been updated since 2015.